# how can i start my project when Pi is Turn On or Plugged In -Raspberry pi 3b+

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python, pi-2

need to run my python file when raspberry PI is turned on or plugged in.
I'm using Raspberry Pi 3B+

**sudo nano /etc/rc.local**

> this is not Working

```
# rc.local
 #
 # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
 # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
 # value on error.
 #
 # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
 # bits.
 #
 # By default this script does nothing.
 # Print the IP address if it doesn't work ad sleep 30 before all your code 
 _IP=$(hostname -I) || true
 if [ "$_IP" ]; then
   printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
   python /home/pi/Code/openCamera.py 
 fi
 exit 0
```

Comment: `this is not Working` - none of it? or just your pythin part of it? Dont' forget, running from rc.local you a) run as root, and b) home folder will be /root and c) current working folder will be ?? / maybe or /root ?? You need to make sure your environment is correct, i.e. user, home folder and current folder if your pythin expects the current working directory to be something specific

Comment: personally, I'd be looking at creating a systemd service - much easier to have all that set up

Comment: can you please guide me on this..@JaromandaX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's how I'd do it

create a shell script in /home/pi - called `openCamera.sh`

```
cat > ~/openCamera.sh <<-EOF
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/Code
python openCamera.py
EOF
```

make it executable

```
chmod u+x openCamera.sh
```

Create a service for this program

```
sudo cat > /etc/systemd/system/openCamera.service <<-EOF
[Unit]
Description=Open Camera Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=pi
Group=pi
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/pi/openCamera.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

enable and start the service

```
sudo systemctl enable openCamera.service
sudo systemctl start openCamera.service
```

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl enable openCamera.service
Failed to enable unit: File openCamera.service: Invalid argument

Comment: really? `cat /etc/systemd/system/openCamera.service` does it look right?

Comment: yes, I know it's an error, maybe you did it wrong

Comment: what should we do know?

Comment: did you run all of the code in the code block after `Create a service for this program`

Comment: see the text between `<<-EOF` and `EOF` - copy that, create the file `/etc/systemd/system/openCamera.service` and paste the text into that file, save it, then try enable again

Comment: Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/openCamera.service → /etc/systemd/system/openCamera.service.   **Done**

Comment: cool, now `sudo systemctl start openCamera.service` should proceed without error - reboot, and see if it works - by the way `After=network.target` may not be right (I copied my own service for that part)

Comment: sudo systemctl start openCamera.service **Done**

Comment: no errors? reboot and see if it works

Comment: **after reboot** . as usual opened my raspberry pi dashboard.

Comment: no idea what you mean - is that a good thing?

Comment: after reboot...opened raspberry pi home.

Comment: again, what were you expecting? perhaps you need to be **clear** in the question what you are expecting, not just "this is not working" ... what do you expect your pythin stuff to achieve?

Comment: openCamera.py is running but my camera light is just blinked and gone.

Comment: whenever my raspberry is plugged in or turned on needs to run that opencamera.py file

Comment: yes, check if the process is running ... if it's running then it's running - if it isn't then theres some error, I can't see your system, so you'll need to find the error - start by `sudo systemctl status openCamera.service`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `systemd` that some find easier to use is `cron`. If you want your script to run at startup, try this:

1. While logged in as user `pi` for example, open your `crontab` file using the `nano` editor (`$` is the `bash` prompt):

`$ crontab -e`

2. In the last line of the `crontab` file, add the following:

```
@reboot ( /bin/sleep 30; /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Code/openCamera.py > /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1)
```

Save your file (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>), exit `nano` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>), then reboot (`sudo reboot`) your RPi.

A couple of notes re the above:
1. We `sleep` for 30 seconds after the system starts the `cron` daemon to give the system time to get everything else we need started. 30 seconds is an **approximation**; it might be less, occasionally it may be more (unlikely, but possible). You can experiment with this value to find one that works best for your system.
2. Any errors that are generated while starting your script will be written to a file in your (pi's) home directory: `/home/pi/cronjoblog`. Check the contents of this file if your script fails to start.